# Blazeds dynamic destination

Tags: dynamic, blazeds

I'm trying to create dynamic destinations using BlazeDS. To start with I used the 'Feed' sample that comes with BlazeDS. It has a destination defined as 'feed' in messaging-config.xml. Now I commented the destination in messaging-config.xml and added the following code in Feed.java, to create dynamic destination

```
MessageService service = (MessageService) msgBroker.getService("message-service");
Destination destination = service.createDestination("feed");
if (service.isStarted()) {
destination.start();
System.out.println("Started destination....");
}
```

On the Java side it doesn't throw any error. But this doesn't work on the Flex side as it doesn't find the dynamically created destination.